# byte values in hex format and writes these to the byte stream?

Tags: java

Takes a sequence of byte values in hex format and writes these to the byte stream.
      "01 02 1a" => writes bytes 0x01 0x02 0x1a to the byte stream.

What does this mean?

Comment: "A sequence of byte values in hex format", is this a string of hex formatted byte values or an array of bytes?  "writes to the byte stream", are you referring to a file?

Comment: string of hex formatted byte values "01, 02, 1a"

Comment: What is your byte stream? Are you writing the results to a file using FileOutputStream or are you wanting to write this out as plain text to show 0x01 0x02 0x1a? I ask because actual byte values in a file will not have the "0x" preceding the values.

Comment: It should be added to ByteBuffer

Comment: You're not going to see 0x01 0x02 0x1a in a ByteBuffer.  Please be more specific as to what you're wanting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
    String hex = "01 02 1a";

    // Remove spaces
    hex = hex.replace(" ", "");

    // Array containing bytes
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.length() / 2];

    int k = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < hex.length(); i = i +2 ) {
        // Read and parse each byte
        int b = Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(i, i + 2), 16);
        bytes[k] = (byte) b;
        k++;
    }

    // Write bytes to an outputStram
    OutputStream out;
    for(Byte b: bytes) {
        out.write(b);
    }
```

Comment: 0x01 0x02 0x1a  this should be the output

Comment: Yes, it means you have write each byte to an outputStream: `for(Byte b: bytes) outputStream.write(b);`

Comment: I added it to my post.